# How do I get distinct objects with mongoose with specific conditions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I've got the following model in my Node.JS project:

```
const Activity = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        require: [true, "A activity must have a name"]
    },
    city: {
        type: String,
        require: [true, "A location must have a city"]
    },
    country: {
        type: String,
        require: [true, "A location must have a county"]
    },
});
```

(I omitted some attributes to make it easier, _id is generated by Mongo automatically)

What I now want to achieve is to get a list of all distinct locations. So basically in SQL:
SELECT city,country FROM Activity WHERE city=regEx OR country=regEx;

What I tried so far:

```
let result = await Activity.find({$or: [{city: regEx}, {region: regEx}, {country: regEx}]}, "region city country -_id");
result = fastSet(result);
```

... where fastSet() is a function which removes duplicates. But now I want to do this in one query. What I found so far is that I can use aggregate() with $match (and $or inside), then maybe group and project but I guess I don't get the expected result if I use group here.

An example of the right result would be:

```
let result = [{city:"City A", country:"Country A"}, {city:"City B", country:"Country A"}, {city:"City C", country:"Country C"}];
```

...and so on.
How do I achieve that?

Comment: let result = await Activity.find({$or: [{city: regEx}, {region: regEx}, {country: regEx}]}, "region city country -_id").sort({field : 1}).distinct('field');

Comment: But with "distinct" I can only use city, region OR country, right? That was my problem so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need 2 stages in an aggregation pipeline: [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html#match-aggregation) to test the regular expressions, and [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#group-aggregation) with all of the fields you want to distinct inside the _id.

```
.aggregate([
   {$match:{
      $or:[
           {city: regEx},
           {country: regEx},
           {region: regEx}
          ]
   }},
   {$group:{
      _id: {
             city: "$city",
             country: "$country"
           }
   }}
])
```

Comment: Ok, I didn't think you can just group by two attributes at the same time. But wouldn't the format of the response include _id? How would I get rid of it? With project()?

Comment: Yes, use $project to reshape the object.